# What is hive's equivalent of "select ... into outfile"?

Tags: sql, hive

How would I do this in Hive?

```
select * from mytable into outfile "/tmp/foo"
```

Or any variant of this; I just need to be able to save this data to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY 'someDir' SELECT ...
```